# Pandas groupby mean() drops a column in output

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm new to python and trying to understand why a column is dropped when running a mean summary groupby drops one of my columns.

```
cols = ['day','time','weather']
metrics = ['amt','cost','duration']
```

```
def avg_metrics(df):
    df1 = df.groupby(cols[0],as_index=False)[metrics[0:len(metrics)]].mean()\
    .sort_values(metrics[0],ascending=False).drop_duplicates()
    return df1
avg_metrics(sample)
```

I then get an error saying that 'amt' cannot be found and it has been dropped after trying to sort by 'amt' in the second line. How do I groupby and run mean() to keep all columns?

Comment: Peripheral to the problem but unless i'm missing something `[metrics[0:len(metrics)]]` is unecessary (and confusing), just do `[metrics]`

Comment: Your `amt` column is probably a string -- so a mean can't be found.